# How TO write RFID Tag for Nexus S NFC to read?

Tags: android, rfid, nfc, nexus-s

Does anyone know if there are any specifics on writing info into a RFID tag and reading it from Android, Nexus S?

Is there special RFID tag just for Android, or a special RFID writer?

Answer (score 3):

Android 2.3.3 now supports write capabilities, too. Details which tags are supported are here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.3.html.

I plan to work on several examples how to read and write tags and will publish links on my twitter account @hansamann

Answer (score 1):

Based on [what I came across](http://www.anandtech.com/Show/Index/4059?cPage=5&all=False&sort=0&page=2&slug=nexus-s-and-android-23-review-gingerbread-for-the-holidays), for now Nexus S provides only read functionality for NFC tags and support for other modes is planned.

I don't think there can be a OS or platform specific RFID tag, that would not be a good commercial decision :).

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus S will read Mifare tags.  I have replayed YouTube videos (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eu7fQsPjDls) from a smartcard using the Nexus S.

Comment: I see, so the a link to youtube that is store inside a Mifare tag, and it will recall the video?

Answer (score 0):

The URL was written with another device (Nokia 6212).  I am waiting for the Nexus S update that will enable the phone to write onto the tags.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 tag-writer-apps in the android marketplace: One is from the company NXP, which is selling tags: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nxp.nfc.tagwriter the other from Connectthings https://market.android.com/details?id=com.connecthings.tagwriter

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to write (and reformat RFID cards to use NDEF messages)

```
NdefFormatable format = NdefFormatable.Get(tag);
if (format != null) {
    try {
        format.Connect();
        format.Format(message);
        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

This is in Monodroid but I think the concept is the same in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own NFC tag reader:

Create the Payload and emulate an RFID tag using another android device.
Make sure that you are giving NFC_READ ,NFC_WRITE permisions in the manifest files.